# Trying to find a specific row with a name in that row in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with column A having a list of names in it. I then have a userform that uses those names to make an attendance report. When The enter button is pressed it takes the name and finds what row that name is at then finds the next empty cell in that row and puts the info in that cell. My question is how do I search for that name and get the row that is associated with that name? I have done some research but what I have found I didn't quite understand how they are being implemented. I thought about vlookup but wasn't sure if that would give me the row number?

Comment: please show the code you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a quick `Match()`:

`=Match("MyName",$A$1:$A$10000)`

That should return the row number. Note this is relative. If the name is in `A1`, the above will return `1`.

If you do this, however, `=match("myName",A2:A100)`, and the name is in `A2`, it will also return `1`.

Edit: Sorry, for VBA this should work `worksheetfunction.Match(neName.Value,Range("A1:A100"),0)`

Comment: Thank you ill give it a shot here. All the names are in the same column so it should be fine.

Comment: Ok so when I put this in where the enter button is pressed It comes up with a compiler error expected list separator or ). The code I have is Match(NEName.Value,A1:A100,0)

Comment: @DakotaMiller - You'll need to translate this to VBA. I think it'd be `worksheetfunction.Match(neName.Value,Range("A1:A100"),0)`

Comment: Thank You! It worked like it should, ill mark this as the answer!